# How to keep scrolling without ending in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a long list or long vector of genes and I want it to keep scrolling down but it ends and I am not sure if this can be controlled. Any Suggestions? It is suppose to go all the way to Z letter but it stops here. Maybe it is too much, I think there are more than 20,000 genes

[image]

```
# This is where I get my names in that list. 

 observeEvent(data, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'foo11', choices = rownames(data)[order(rownames(data))], server = TRUE)
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(data, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'foo22', choices = rownames(data)[order(rownames(data))], server = TRUE)
  })
```

Comment: Good luck scrolling 20000 elements. :)

Comment: I am not so sure but I found something related on [github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2350) .

Comment: You don't want your users to scroll 20k, as long as they can type and search, should be fine. scrolling 20k is bad for your server load and user experience.